# Powerpoint-like animations with beamer and the animate package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lengths, animations, animate

I want to achieve a simple "fly-in"-animation with LaTeX by utilizing the `animate`-package. My idea was to insert an `\hspace` with decreasing length-argument. However, there is no animation at all.

MWE (adapted from http://texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-definite-integral/):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate, ifthen}

\newcounter{m}
\setcounter{m}{0}

\newlength{\dummy}
\setlength{\dummy}{8cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{animateinline}{2}
            \whiledo{\them < 21} {  % Execute 21 times
                \hspace{\dummy} Hello.
                \addtolength{\dummy}{-.4cm} % Decrease \dummy
                \stepcounter{m}
                \ifthenelse{\them < 21} {
                    \newframe % Create new frame, if condition satisfied
                }{
                    \end{animateinline}\relax % Otherwise end environment
                }
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Maybe i should just use TikZ to modify coordinates/parameters like this, but i initially thought, this should work and would be a more minimal way to achieve my goals.

Why isn't this working? What would be a better approach if mine was wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\whiledo` for building loops around parameterized animation frames is deprecated. It may lead to unexpected results, because `\newframe` embedded into its loop body may hide local assignments of dimensions and counters.

Instead, use pkg `animate`'s built-in command `\multiframe`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Fly-in example}
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{20}
      \multiframe{21}{dim=8cm+-0.4cm}{
        \makebox[\widthof{\hspace{8cm}Hello.}][l]{\strut\hspace{\dim}Hello.}
      }
    \end{animateinline}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what i hoped to achieve. Also thanks for the pointer of `\whiledo` being deprecated. I didn't know that!

Comment: @Tim I added a bit of explanation.